# What does the python re.template function do?

Tags: python, regex

While using the re module in ipython I noticed an undocumented `template` function:

```
In [420]: re.template?
Type:           function
Base Class:     <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function template at 0xb7eb8e64>
Namespace:      Interactive
File:           /usr/tideway/lib/python2.7/re.py
Definition:     re.template(pattern, flags=0)
Docstring:
    Compile a template pattern, returning a pattern object
```

there is also a flag `re.TEMPLATE` and its alias `re.T`.

None of this is mentioned in the docs for either 2.7 or 3.2.  What do they do?  Are they obsolete hangovers from an earlier version of Python, or an experimental feature that may be officially added in the future?

Comment: Where are the Python devs like [ncoghlan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/597742/ncoghlan) when you need them?

Comment: This was described in http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2000-June/005143.html and I think you might have to ask Frederik Lundh if you want to know what it was supposed to do or why it is still there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In CPython 2.7.1, [`re.template()` is defined](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e685b02ddcac/Lib/re.py#l213) as:

```
def template(pattern, flags=0):
    "Compile a template pattern, returning a pattern object"
    return _compile(pattern, flags|T)
```

`_compile` calls `_compile_typed` which calls `sre_compile.compile`. The only place in the code where the `T` (aka `SRE_FLAG_TEMPLATE`) flag is checked is [in that function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e685b02ddcac/Lib/sre_compile.py#l64):

```
    elif op in REPEATING_CODES:
        if flags & SRE_FLAG_TEMPLATE:
            raise error, "internal: unsupported template operator"
            emit(OPCODES[REPEAT])
            skip = _len(code); emit(0)
            emit(av[0])
            emit(av[1])
            _compile(code, av[2], flags)
            emit(OPCODES[SUCCESS])
            code[skip] = _len(code) - skip
    ...
```

This would have the effect of disabling all repetition operators (`*`, `+`, `?`, `{}` etc):

```
In [10]: re.template('a?')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.....
error: internal: unsupported template operator
```

The way the code is structured (the unconditional `raise` preceding a bunch of dead code) makes me think that the feature was either never fully implemented, or has been turned off due to some problems. I can only guess what the intended semantics may have been.

The end result is that the function does nothing useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I should have taken a peek at the source before asking the question.  It seems strange that it is still explicitly exported in the `__all__` list when the only thing it does is fail with an exception.